# Flask is not adding fields to my request in url_for method

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2

### Flask is not adding request fields to my url_for method.

For example I have a list of fields, each of which is a dictionary containing print and path items.

```
 {% for i,field in enumerate(fields) %}
 {% set field_print = field['print'] %}
 {% set new_path = field['path'] %}
  <tr style="height:0px">
    <td >
      <pre style="LINE-HEIGHT:3px;">
        <a href= {{ url_for('add_field' ,my_path=new_path) }}>
           {{ field_print }}
        </a>
      </pre>
    </td>
    <td>
 </tr>
```

For some reason, the url_for is generating the following url

```
http://myapp:50001/add_field/whatever_is_in_the_new_path_variable
```

I would expect it to generate the following url

```
http://myapp:50001/add_field?my_path=whatever_is_in_the_new_path_variable
```

Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the type and what is `new_path` in the console log?

Comment: The type  is string.
I have solved the issue. It seems that the handler for the add_field url should not have my_path as a parameter. Otherwise it strips the parameter. For example my handler had the signature
```
       @app.route('/add_field')
       @app.route("/add_field/<my_path>")
       def add_field(my_path=None)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. It seems that the handler for the add_field url should not have my_path as a parameter. Otherwise it strips the parameter. For example my handler had the signature

```
@app.route('/add_field') 
@app.route("/add_field/<my_path>") 
def add_field(my_path=None)
```

changing the signature to the below solved the issue

```
@app.route('/add_field') 
def add_field()
```